# CSS + jQ plugin preventing AJAX call / event listener from working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got superfish working now and its preventing an ajax call (or rather the event listener ) from triggering, when I commented out the initialization of the plugin, the event is called however it retrieves the wrong set of data. jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dFwn7/1/

Any idea why calling:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
});
```

Causes the event listener (form submit) to fail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely: It's because your fish is not defined before it is being called.

Any undefined method would actually break your code, for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dFwn7/2/

Make sure to add your custom method before you call it.

Or, there is an error in the plugin itself (also possible);